# How do I compose email first and then add a group to the bcc line?

Tags: mail.app, email

I like to compose my email messages first and then add recipients.  I created a smart group that I would like to add to the BCC line after composing a message, however I can't seem to find a way to do this.  I am using the default Mail application.

Comment: What program are you using? What operating system?

Comment: Please provide us with more details according to your system so we can help you out!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem well enough, in the Apple Mail program, once you have written your email you can click on View->BCC Address Field and that should open the BCC space to add your group.